# Drive API 404 creating file inside a folder

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, drive

I am trying to create a file in a folder on my drive.

The folder exists in my drive and it's shared with the account I'm using (in the code I will refer to it with the fake ID: 1AKIQHcwQVYgGcinp335Uu5C24kI1tJaq)

This is my code to create the file

```
from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

def create_file(service, title, description, parent_id, mime_type, filename):

  media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
  body = {
          'name': title,
          'title': title,
          'description': description,
          'mimeType': mime_type,
          'parents': [parent_id]
          }
  try:
      file = service.files().create(
              body=body,
              media_body=media_body,
              fields='id').execute()
      return file
  except errors.HttpError as error:
      print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
      return None
```

But I'm always getting this error:

```
<HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=resumable returned "File not found: 1AKIQHcwQVYgGcinp335Uu5C24kI1tJaq.">
```

I based my code on [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder), is there something I'm missing? Can the problem to the fact that the folder is inside of a gsuite shared drive?

Comment: make sure the user you are authorizing with has access to that directory.

Comment: If the user has access to that directory, can you confirm if your parent_id is valid? 404 error is sometimes being caused by an invalid parent_id. There might be a typo somewhere. Log the parent ID and test it by visiting the link `https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/u/0/folders/ + parent_id`.

Comment: Thanks, found the mistake.
To use a folder in a shared drive you have to provide the driveId

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution!

To use a folder in a shared drive you have to provide the driveId:

```
from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

def create_file(service, title, description, parent_id, drive_id, mime_type, filename):

  media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
  body = {
          'name': title,
          'title': title,
          'description': description,
          'mimeType': mime_type,
          'parents': [parent_id],
          'driveId': drive_id
          }
  try:
      file = service.files().create(
              body=body,
              media_body=media_body,
              fields='id').execute()
      return file
  except errors.HttpError as error:
      print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
      return None
```

Comment: The one I don't like with the error codes being shown is it being too general. A lot of different issues return 404 and you need to check it all out. Glad you were still able to solve it on your own.

Comment: @davide what is the driveId btw? how to get that?